# Creating dictionary of dictionaries including other data types

Tags: python, dictionary

Consider the following .csv:

```
country:     region:         rank1:    rank2:    rank3:
switzerland   West Europe      1         7.25     0.04
Iceland       West Europe      2         7.04     1.03
Canada        North America    3         7.32     0.03
```

I need to create a dictionary in the following structure, with one big dictionary containing dictionaries for each region containing another dictionary for countries, with tuples for the ranks (rank 1 and 2 contained in the same tuple). Like this:

```
{
'Western Europe':
   {'switzerland': ((1, 7.25), (0.04)),
    'Iceland': ((2, 7.04), (1.03))
    ...}
'North America':
   {'Canada': ((3, 7.32), (0.03))
 ...}
}
```

Should I first read in the columns to be tuples, then create dictionaries of the countries containing those tuples? then add those to dictionaries of region?

```
import csv

def build_dict():
    d={}
    with open('2015.csv', mode='r') as fp:
    reader = csv.reader(fp)
    next(fp, None)
    #problem area
    for row in reader:
        key = row[0]
        if key in d:
            pass
        d[key] = row[1:]
    print(d)
```

Which I'm aware gives me a dictionary that I don't want (dictionary with dictionaries for each country), but I've never worked with this many nested data structures and if anybody could show me the light I would be very grateful. I just feel like there's a lot going on here, and there's got to be an efficient way to do something like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you need.

```
import csv

def build_dict():
    d={}
    with open('2015.csv', mode='r') as fp:
        reader = csv.reader(fp)
        next(fp, None)
        for row in reader:
            key = row[1]
            if not key in d: #If this is a region we haven't seen yet
                d[key] = {} #Add it to the top-level dictionary
            d[key][row[0]] = ((row[2], row[3]), row[4]) #Fill in data for that country
    print(d)
```

There's probably a much better way to do this with something like pandas, but this gets the job done while being close to your original code.

Comment: Thank you so much! let me give it a try. I appreciate the raw answer though I'm sure learning to utilize pandas would be beneficial

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to work with Pandas (excuse me for not working with your code):
Load the dictionary as a DataFrame, group by region, and iterate over the grouped sub-DataFrames. There might be more efficient solutuons without iterating for countries inside each region.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('2015.csv')
d = {} # initiate an empty dictionary
for region, df_region in df.groupby(by='region'):
    # region is the region name (string), and df_region is a small DataFrame with only one region.
    d_region = {} # a new sub-dictionary for each region
    for row in df_region.iterrows():
        # each row is a pandas.Series object representing a different country.
        # we can access its values by, for example, row['country']
        d_region[row['country']] = ((row['rank1'], row['rank2']), row['rank3'])
    # add to our general dictionary the new sub-dictionary, with region as its key
    d['region'] = d_region
```